# QHash cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class QHash<class QDomElement,class QDomElement>::const_iterator' to '::iterator'

Tags: qt, const-iterator, qhash

I have a qhash defined with key value pair as QDomElement. as given below. I am trying to update the hash by using const_iterator. But while doing so below error is thrown, how to resolve the same:-

```
error C2664: 'erase' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class QHash<class QDomElement,class QDomElement>::const_iterator' to 'class QHash<class QDomElement,class QDomElemen
t>::iterator'
```

Code Snippet :-

```
// update parent child mapping hash
    QHash<QDomElement, QDomElement>::const_iterator pList = hashParentChildList.constBegin();
    while (pList != hashParentChildList.constEnd())
    {
        if(pList.key() == element)
        {
            pList = hashParentChildList.erase(pList); // Error Line
        }
        else
        {
            pList++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, use 
QHash::iterator pList = hashParentChildList.begin();
instead of 
QHash::const_iterator pList = hashParentChildList.constBegin();